# Когда следует использовать ValueTask<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

В новой редакции языка появилось новшество `ValueTask<T>` .

Правильно ли я понимаю, что его следует использовать в том случае, когда есть вероятность, что задача выполнится быстрее,чем я вызову `await`?

Обычный Task умер или все таки в каких-то случаях его нужно использовать?

Comment: Только для функций, которые могут выполниться синхронно и быстро же. Таски совсем для другого. Кратко почитать зачем оно надо - тут http://intellitect.com/generalized-async-return-types/

Comment: Вольный пересказ англ so: Это структура, а значит нет лишней аллокации, но структура должна копироваться, а ее размер больше чем размер ссылки (медленнее копирование, больше размер хранения). Также если попадет в Task.When/Wait, то будет им нужна Task, а значит AsTask() и аллокация. Task - класс, потому что появился до await. Task и ValueTask служат для одинаковых целей, но у каждого свои накладные расходы и нет лидера для всех сценариев

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43000520/2881286

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

описание в разделе [Generalized async return types](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/articles/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types)

> Возврат `Task` из асинхронных методов, в некоторых случаях может стать узким местом в производительности. `Task` – это ссылочный тип, поэтому при его использовании память под объект будет выделяться в куче. В случаях, когда метод с модификатором `async` возвращает кэшированный результат, или выполняется синхронно, дополнительное выделение памяти в куче может занимать значительное время в критических секциях кода. Это может стать очень дорогим, если данные выделения будут происходить в циклах.
>
> новые возможности языка позволяют возвращать из асинхронных методов другие типы, кроме `Task`, `Task<T>` и `void`. Возвращаемый тип по прежнему должен удовлетворять асинхронному шаблону, то есть должен быть доступен метод `GetAwaiter`. В качестве конкретного примере в *.NET framework* был добавлен тип `ValueTask` для использования новой возможности:
>
> ```
> public async ValueTask<int> Func()
> {
>     await Task.Delay(100);
>     return 5;
> }
> ```
>
> Простой оптимизацией может стать использование `ValueTask` там, где ранее использовался `Task`. Однако, если хочется добавить дополнительную оптимизацию вручную, можно кэшировать результаты асинхронной работы и использовать эти результаты в последующих вызовах. У структуры `ValueTask` есть конструктор принимающий `Task` в качестве параметра, так что можно создать `ValueTask` из возвращаемого значения любого существующего асинхронного метода:
>
> ```
> public ValueTask<int> CachedFunc()
> {
>     return (cache) ? new ValueTask<int>(cacheResult) : new ValueTask<int>(LoadCache());
> }
> private bool cache = false;
> private int cacheResult;
> private async Task<int> LoadCache()
> {
>     // simulate async work:
>     await Task.Delay(100);
>     cacheResult = 100;
>     cache = true;
>     return cacheResult;
> }
> ```
>
> Как и в случаях со всеми рекомендациями по производительности, перед внесением в код масштабных изменений следует сравнить результаты обоих подходов.

Comment: _новые возможности языка позволяют возвращать из асинхронных методов другие типы, кроме Task, Task<T> и void. Возвращаемый тип по прежнему должен удовлетворять асинхронному шаблону, то есть должен быть доступен метод GetAwaiter_ - правильно ли я понимаю, что если я создам свой класс/структуру, в которой "доступен метод GetAwaiter", то я смогу писать что-то типа `acync MyTaskClass FunAsync() {...}`?

Comment: @Qutrix по-хорошему, это должен был быть отдельный вопрос.

Comment: К сожалению, в документации как всегда написана глупость. Нет никакого смысла использовать `ValueTask` поверх обычного `Task`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а почему нет смысла, как в примере использовать для кэширования значения?

Comment: @Grundy потому что проще закешировать саму задачу

Answer (score 9):

Небольшое дополнение к ответу [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy) и ответ на комментарий [@Qutrix](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220200/qutrix):

Для того, чтобы компилятор разрешил использовать ваш собственный Task-подобный тип в качестве возвращаемого значения для асинхронных методов необходимо проделать следующие действия:

1. Создать этот тип. Он может быть классом или структурой:

   ```
   public class MyTask { }
   ```
2. Пометить его атрибутом `[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(MyTaskBuilder))]`
3. Реализовать класс/структуру `MyTaskBuilder`. В дальнейшем он будет использоваться компилятором для конструирования вашего Task-подобного типа (минимальный набор методов и свойств указан ниже и *в обязательном порядке* должен присутствовать в определении `MyTaskBuilder`)

```
public class MyTaskBuilder
{
    public static MyTaskBuilder Create() => new MyTaskBuilder();

    public void Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }

    public void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine) { }

    public void SetResult() { }

    public void SetException(Exception exception) { }

    public MyTask Task { get; }

    public void AwaitOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter, ref TStateMachine stateMachine)
        where TAwaiter : INotifyCompletion where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }

    public void AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TAwaiter, TStateMachine>(ref TAwaiter awaiter,
        ref TStateMachine stateMachine) where TAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        where TStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine { }
}
```

4. И, наконец, для поддержки оператора `await` так же необходима реализация в классе `MyTask` открытого метода `GetAwaiter()`, тип возвращаемого значения (`MyTaskAwaiter`) которого должен реализовывать интерфейс [`INotifyCompletion`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion?view=netframework-4.7), иметь открытое свойство `IsCompleted`, и конечно же метод `GetResult()` (который будет возвращать результат асинхронной операции или же void).

---

```
[AsyncMethodBuilder(typeof(MyTaskBuilder))]
public class MyTask
{
    public static MyTask Run(Action action) { }

    public MyTaskAwaiter GetAwaiter() { }
}

public class MyTaskAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    public bool IsCompleted { get; }

    public void GetResult() { }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) { }
}
```

---

Таким образом мы получили возможность писать что-то вроде

```
private async MyTask ExecuteAsync()
{
    await MyTask.Run(() => { });
}
```

Comment: Отличное дополнение, только не понятно почему в доках пишется то, что пишется (_Возвращаемый тип по прежнему должен удовлетворять асинхронному шаблону, то есть должен быть доступен метод GetAwaiter_), и почему текст ошибки компилятора все еще такой: "The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>"? А где Вы прочитали про Ваше дополнение?

Comment: @Qutrix я изучил исходники `ValueTask<T>`, затем попробовал написать свой такой тип. По поводу сообщения компилятора - см. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12621 , это должны исправить. Ну а в новых доках я уже не первый раз замечаю неточности, можете запостить [сюда](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues) сообщение о том, что статья нуждается в улучшении. Либо можно исправить самостоятельно и отправить pull request туда же.

Comment: Поставил минус чтобы дополнение к ответу не оказалось выше ответа...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно было не ставить :-) порядок сортировки может не зависеть от голосов

Comment: @Grundy но обычно все-таки зависит

Answer (score 5):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что его следует использовать в том случае, когда есть вероятность, что задача выполнится быстрее,чем я вызову await?

В целом верно, но с небольшой поправкой: когда есть вероятность, что задача выполнится *без прерывания выполнения*. Или, что то же самое, если он может выполниться синхронно. Это не то же самое, что без вызова await, потому что оператор await не прерывает выполнение метода если он вызван над уже завершенной задачей.

К примеру, метод ниже будет выполнен синхронно:

```
async ValueTask<bool> Foo() {
    await Task.Completed;
    await Task.FromResult(1);
    return await Task.FromResult(false);
}
```